# No history for current tag-wiki contribution

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-wiki, revision-history

When submitting a tag-wiki edit, and when waiting for it to be reviewed, there is no way that the contributor sees the actual contribution in the history. In this manner, there is no way to check for possible errors on that level.

Suggestion: Make the pending contribution visible in the history for the submitter.

Comment: You have to notice the *edit pending* link which brings you on the review task. For Q/A posts you also don't see the pending edit among the edits so I'm not sure why it is important to have a different behavior on wiki's, given you can see the current proposed change. Or I miss the point ...

Comment: @rene: That would be an improvement for the actual submitter of the edit not for reviewers.

Comment: What you want is the same feature when you propose an edit to a Q/A on a site where you don't have full edit privileges. You'll see your edited version with a notice at the top that it still needs to be reviewed, right?

Comment: @rene: Right! ! !

Comment: @animuson: It's the history which is lacking!

Comment: Like you want the edit to actually appear in the *revision history* for the post before it's been approved?

Comment: @animuson: Exactly! In this manner I can check for consistency and the like

Comment: That's... never ever going to happen. The revision history is for *history* of the post, not for the potential future.

Comment: @animuson: For the submitter, it's not the future

Comment: Yes, it is. That edit could still completely disappear for you. What exact functionality do you want out of this? if you're looking for diffs, you can just visit the suggested edit itself and look at diffs there.

Comment: @animuson: Where do I see the difs for a tag-wiki edit as long as it is pending??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17930234 - You get the rendered output diff and the markdown diff. Works for tag wikis too.

Comment: That's it - how can I figure out that it's nr. 17930234?

Comment: You can find all of your suggested edits in your profile's "all actions" tab.

Comment: Thx!&nbsp;&nbsp;